# Delphi XE2 Indy 10.5.92 GMail SMTP error "Username and Password not accepted"

Tags: delphi, gmail, delphi-xe2, indy10

My question is: why gmail gives me that error:

Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=14257 lp8sm18275694wic.17 - gsmtp

I tried everything, whole bunch of options: SSL, TSL, SASL and still nothing. Somewhere I found that google demands some OAUTH2 SASL method wchich is to be done in Indy.

Of course on Delphi 6 and Indy 9 with proper eay dlls on port 465 with ssl works fine.
Anyone has some idea what to do with that?

O course I installed http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html i anyone asked...

here is the code:

```
procedure send(Recipientemail, AccountName, Pass, EmailSMTP,EmailPortNo :string);
var
  lTextPart: TIdText;
  lImagePart: TIdAttachmentfile;
  IdSMTP1: TIdSMTP;
  IdMsg: TIdMessage;
  SSLHandler:TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
  IdUserPassProv1: TIdUserPassProvider;

  IdSASLLogin1: TIdSASLLogin;
  IdSASLCRAMMD5: TIdSASLCRAMMD5;
  IdSASLCRAMSHA1: TIdSASLCRAMSHA1;
  IdSASLPlain: TIdSASLPlain;
  IdSASLLogin: TIdSASLLogin;
  IdSASLSKey: TIdSASLSKey;
  IdSASLOTP: TIdSASLOTP;
  IdSASLAnonymous: TIdSASLAnonymous;
  IdSASLExternal: TIdSASLExternal;
begin

  IdSMTP1:=TIdSMTP.Create(nil);
  IdMsg:=TIdMessage.Create(nil);
  IdSMTP1.Host:=EmailSMTP;
  IdSMTP1.Port:=EmailPortNo;
  //IdSMTP1.Username:=trim(AccountName);//tried with or without
  //IdSMTP1.Password:=trim(Pass);//tried with or without



    TIdSSLContext.Create.Free;
    SSLHandler:=TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(IdSMTP1);
    SSLHandler.SSLOptions.Method := sslvSSLv3;
    SSLHandler.SSLOptions.Mode := sslmClient;
    IdSMTP1.IOHandler := SSLHandler;

    if (IdSMTP1.port = 465) then
        IdSMTP1.UseTLS := utUseImplicitTLS
      else
        IdSMTP1.UseTLS := utUseExplicitTLS;

    IdSASLLogin1:=TIdSASLLogin.Create(IdSMTP1);
    IdUserPassProv1:=TIdUserPassProvider.Create(IdSMTP1);
    IdUserPassProv1.Password:=trim(EmailHasloKonta);
    IdUserPassProv1.Username:=trim(EmailNazwaKonta);

    IdSMTP1.AuthType:=satSASL;

    IdSASLCRAMSHA1 := TIdSASLCRAMSHA1.Create(idSMTP1);
    IdSASLCRAMSHA1.UserPassProvider := IdUserPassProv1;
    IdSASLCRAMMD5 := TIdSASLCRAMMD5.Create(idSMTP1);
    IdSASLCRAMMD5.UserPassProvider := IdUserPassProv1;
    IdSASLSKey := TIdSASLSKey.Create(idSMTP1);
    IdSASLSKey.UserPassProvider := IdUserPassProv1;
    IdSASLOTP := TIdSASLOTP.Create(idSMTP1);
    IdSASLOTP.UserPassProvider := IdUserPassProv1;
    IdSASLAnonymous := TIdSASLAnonymous.Create(idSMTP1);
    IdSASLExternal := TIdSASLExternal.Create(idSMTP1);
    IdSASLLogin := TIdSASLLogin.Create(idSMTP1);
    IdSASLLogin1.UserPassProvider:=IdUserPassProv1;
    IdSASLPlain := TIdSASLPlain.Create(idSMTP1);
    IdSASLPlain.UserPassProvider := IdUserPassProv1;

    IdSMTP1.SASLMechanisms.Add.SASL := IdSASLCRAMSHA1;
    IdSMTP1.SASLMechanisms.Add.SASL := IdSASLCRAMMD5;
    IdSMTP1.SASLMechanisms.Add.SASL := IdSASLSKey;
    IdSMTP1.SASLMechanisms.Add.SASL := IdSASLOTP;
    IdSMTP1.SASLMechanisms.Add.SASL := IdSASLAnonymous;
    IdSMTP1.SASLMechanisms.Add.SASL := IdSASLExternal;
    IdSMTP1.SASLMechanisms.Add.SASL := IdSASLLogin1;
    IdSMTP1.SASLMechanisms.Add.SASL := IdSASLPlain;

  IdMsg.CharSet:=CmbEncod.Text;
  IdMsg.From.Address:=EmailAdresNadawcy;
  IdMsg.From.Name:=ToISO_8859_2(true, EmailNadawca);

  IdMsg.Recipients.Add.Address:=email;
  if EmailDoWiad<>'' then IdMsg.BccList.Add.Address:=EmailDoWiad;

  IdMsg.ContentType:='multipart/relative';//; charset='+CmbEncod.Text;
  IdMsg.Subject:=ifthen(TytulEmaila='',translate('Potwierdzenie rezerwacji'),TytulEmaila);
  IdMsg.Body.Clear;
  IdMsg.Body.Text:='';

  lTextPart := TIdText.Create(IdMsg.MessageParts);
  lTextPart.Body.text:='Some body text';
  lTextPart.ContentType := 'text/plain';

  try
     IdSMTP1.Connect;     
     //IdSMTP1.Authenticate; //tried with or without

     try

      try
      IdSMTP1.Send(IdMsg);
      except
        on e: exception do
         MessageDlg('Sending error:'#13+
                  e.message,
                  mtinformation,[mbok],0);
      end;
     finally
        IdSMTP1.Disconnect;
     end;
   finally
     IdSMTP1.Disconnect;
     IdUserPassProv1.free;
     IdSASLLogin1.free;
     IdSASLCRAMMD5.free;
     IdSASLCRAMSHA1.free;
     IdSASLPlain.free;
     IdSASLLogin.free;
     IdSASLSKey.free;
     IdSASLOTP.free;
     IdSASLAnonymous.free;
     IdSASLExternal.free;
     lTextPart.Free;
     lImagePart.Free;
     SSLHandler.free;
     IdSMTP1.Free;
     IdMsg.Free;
     SSLHandler.Free;
   end;
end;
```

Answer (score 5):

Using the latest Indy version (10.6.1), I can successfully connect and authenticate `TIdSMTP` to Gmail using Indy's SASL components with both SSL (`UseTLS=utUseImplicitTLS` on port 465) and TLS (`UseTLS=utUseExplicitTLS` on port 587) using similar code to what you have shown.  Despite popular belief, OAUTH2 is *not* required yet.

The fact that you are getting a human-readable authentication error means the SSL/TLS portion is working fine, so this is strictly a SASL issue.

If your Gmail account is using 2-step verification, make sure you have created an *Application Password* in your Gmail account settings, you cannot use your primary Gmail password.  Read Gmail's documentation for more details:

[Application-specific password required](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/1173270)

[Sign in using App Passwords](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833)

With that said, the only changes I would suggest you make to the code you have showed are:

1. setting the `UseTLS` property may change the `Port` property value, so you should set `UseTLS` first and then set the `Port` to the desired value afterwards:

   ```
   if (EmailPortNo = 465) then
     IdSMTP1.UseTLS := utUseImplicitTLS
   else
     IdSMTP1.UseTLS := utUseExplicitTLS;
   IdSMTP1.Port := EmailPortNo;
   ```
2. you do not need to create and destroy a `TIdSSLContext` object, so get rid of that.  The only reason to create a `TIdSSLContext` manually is so it can call the `IdSSLOpenSSL.LoadOpenSSLLibrary()` function, which is public so you can call it directly if needed (which you don't really need to in this situation).
3. `multipart/relative` is not a valid ContentType.  Did you mean `multipart/related` instead?  Your `TIdMessage` does not contain multiple parts so you should not be using `multipart` ContentType to begin with.
4. Most of your calls to `Free()` are redundant since you assigned the `TIdSMTP` as the Owner for everything except the `TIdMessage`.  You don't need to free the SASL components manually, you can let `TIdSMTP` do that for you.
5. you are calling `IdSMTP1.Disconnect()` twice.  You don't need that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

After all tries is seems to I have had the wrong version of two dlls libeay.dll and ssleay.dll.